# Wordpress Widget With Single Column Was Transformed To Three Column With Custom CSS. Results not as expected

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Our website is here - https://www.tnilive.com

I have been using a widget from the theme that shows recent/latest posts as a single column.

However, I used some very basic CSS skills and used the code from this page - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-gap to convert the single column to three columns.

The latest posts are coming as three columns. But their order and alignment are all jumbled up. They are showing up the same way on mobiles also. Is there a way for me to align these 15 latest posts in three columns on desktop and two columns on mobile properly? Please advice. Thank you.

Used this CSS code exactly

````
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;

  -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 40px;```
````

Comment: "align properly" is a subjective term.  Please create an [mcve] - a link to your live site is useless to future visitors when the site is down, fixed, different, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Here is what I was referring to - https://i.imgur.com/FtIyZ0d.png . If you look at that image, you can clearly see how the posts are not lining up with each other. Thank you.

Comment: Lining up _how_? Vertically? Horizontally? What layout do you want, exactly? Show an example of the desired layout - a good question includes the specific desired outcome.